When deploying to google cloud , my app can't connect to sql database from cloud
I'm facing a deployment issue with a Spring Boot application that's throwing a BeanCreationException during startup. The application works perfectly in the local development environment but fails when deployed with the following error related to the JdbcSessionDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcSessionDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/JdbcSessionConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.JdbcSessionDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'jdbcSessionDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine DatabaseDriver

In my project, I got a file called application.properties, and everything is setup correctly, the credentials for my database are good, on my local testing, everything seems fine, I can modify in the database(delete , add, seek a item). The problem arises when I try to deploy the app(using docker containers) to Google Cloud. Now, the problem that I think it is, is that when deployed the app can't communicate with the sql database, I think this may be the problem cause I got an issue early in development when testing locally did not have access to the sql database until I put my IP address on the firewall(or something like that, now I enabled the private IP assignment). In this link https://pastebin.com/4hGewVv7 is the logs i got from Google Cloud. Any tips are welcomed, I tried everything (didn't use Kubernetes on this project).

Where are you deploying your application to, Cloud Run? If you are attempting to connect to the Private IP address of your Cloud SQL instance, you will need to configure either a serverless VPC access connector or direct VPC egress to Cloud Run in order for your private connection to be established.
